# Docker, Runned mysql container with port forwarding is stopped immediately as soon as it launched

Tags: mysql, docker

I have got a problem with launching MySQL container.

I run MySQL container with below command:

> $ sudo docker run -d --name stockdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yang1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=stkanalysis mysql:5.7 -p 3307:3306

and checked result using

> $ sudo docker ps -a

This is the result.

> CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES
>   34e98ad90f73 mysql:5.7 “docker-entrypoint…” 2 seconds ago Exited (1) 1 second ago stockdb

When I launched same MySQL container without option -p, it worked well like this:

> $ sudo docker run -d --name stockdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yang1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=stkanalysis mysql:5.7

But, whenever I put the port forwarding option -p, running container is failed(technically, it is exited as soon as runed)

I hope to run MySQL container with port forwarding to connect its DBMS from outside host.

I’m using Ubuntu 16.04 and Docker version is 17.09.0-ce.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

The cause was the position of option -p located at the end of commend.

I moved option -p statement forward, and it works well now.

> > $ sudo docker run --name stockdb **-p 3307:3306 -p 3308:22** -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=yang1234 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=stkanalysis mysql:5.7

thank you.